# Wordpress - Fatal Error: "Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object" but only if not as Template

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, wordpress

I get "Fatal Error: "Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object"

with this code in search.php:

```
global $owndb;
$testtable = $owndb -> prefix. "stuff";
$values = $owndb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $testtable" );
```

$owndb is created with `new wpdb` in my plugin which is active. search.php is located in the theme folder under "page-templates" but it is not defined as a template. The file is just called by a JavaScript file to send data. If I declare it as a template (add "Template Name" at the beginning) the error is gone. I tried to store the search.php in different locations (e.g. plugin directory) but this did not help.

Why do I have to declare it as a template and how could I circumvent this?

I saw several questions on the error but not with a solution that fits. Thanks!

Comment: What is `$owndb`. Shouldn't it be `$wpdb` ?

Comment: `$owndb` is not an object, and it doesn't have the same members as `$wpdb`, you'll have to show us how you create it ?

Comment: $owndb is an external database, not the one Wordpress uses. The connection to this db is established in my plugin with $owndb = new wpdb(); This works as I get data out of the db when I declare search.php as a template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. When search.php is not declared as a template (or plugin) it works outside of Wordpress. To use `$owndb` and the Wordpress globals I have to require loading the wp-load.php at the beginning of my search.php:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'wp-load.php');
```

Comment: You missed a "/", it should be: `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');`